# Ambiguity with package statement in java

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
package com.a.b;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello to the world of packages");   
    }
}
```

I've compiled the program like so:

```
javac Test.java
```

This created `Test.class` file in the current working directory. How should I run the program now? I tried:

```
java Test
```

but I'm getting a "No class def found error". If I compile this way:

```
javac -d . Test.java
```

It's creating directory structure, then I'm able to run through

```
java com.a.b.Test
```

If I can compile without directory hierarchy, why can't I execute?

Comment: Hint: all of that is nicely documented. I understand that is convenient to **ask** such things; hoping that somebody takes the time to **explain** things to you, but well, some things are really low level. So, honestly: put some energy in doing prior research. You learn more from finding resources, reading them, digesting and trying ... than "ready to serve answers".

Comment: @GhostCat Sure. I shall keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 3):

In your first command:

```
javac Test.java
```

It compiles fine because there are no errors and places the `Test.class` file in the current directory, because that's where `Test.java` resides, [as per the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> If the *-d* option is not specified, then `javac` puts each class file in the same directory as the source file from which it was generated.

The source file is in the current directory so the class file is placed in the current directory. Now when you execute like so:

```
java Test
```

There's an error because *you must use the fully qualified class name*. You specified a package, and even though it's in the current directory, you still must use the fully qualified name to specify where it is. Without the full name, Java can't find it an execute it, thus the error. You can do the following:

```
java com.a.b.Test
```

Java will find it appropriately and all will execute fine.

---

Now, I would recommend using the `-d` option to correctly place your class files for organization. I would also recommend actually *creating* the packages you specify, so put your `Test.java` file in the directory `./com/a/b`.

Answer (score 2):

You must **always** run your Java program with the fully qualified class name:

It doesn't matter whether you compile it using the `javac -d` option.

So, in your case, it will be:

```
java com.a.b.Test
```

It is a best practice to compile it with the `-d` option and store .class files in the proper directory structure as per the package name.

**Update**

Also, ensure your current directory is in the class-path.

Try running this:

```
java -cp . com.a.b.Test
```

**Update 2**

When the `-d` option is not used with `javac`, the class files are created in the current directory. You will have to move/copy the class file(s) manually to the appropriate directory and then execute them. The `-d` option is a short cut of achieving this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I've mentioned, when I compile through javac Test.java, the .class file is created in the current working directory. Then, I tried to run through java Test, this didn't work (No class def found error)...When I run through java com.a.b.Test, I'm getting could not find or load main class com.a.b.Test

Comment: Have you included the current directory in the class path ?

Comment: Thanks once again. Even with -cp , I'm getting could not find or load main class com.a.b.Test

Answer (score 0):

Java search for classes in `classpath`. By default `classpath` contains only currrent directory.

When Java search for class it iterates thru `classpath` element. If element is directory it search file with name of the class end extension `.class` in some subdirectory. To be precise this subderectory is found by replasing dots to directory separation simbol (`/` or `\` depending on your operation system) and resolving result.

Answer (score -1):

1) Add your class to the java build-path
2) Run it with the **full path.**

Comment: Your answer would make up a terrible comment; but it is a **horrible** answer. "full path" is simply a term that doesn't make sense in the java world. I understand what you want to say, but a newbie will not